# Kotlin Coroutines: one single coroutine at a time in single thread

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Consider this code below, I'm trying to use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1).asCoroutineDispatcher()` to create a single thread dispatcher; I want code within `launch(singleThread){...}` to be executed sequentially 

expected result should be like below because async-block#2 reach/acquire *singleThread* first

> async block #2
> async block #1
> single thread block #2
> single thread block #1
> The answer is 3

but the actual result is

> async block #2
> async block #1
> single thread block #1
> single thread block #2
> The answer is 3

single-thread-block-#2 and single-thread-block-#1 seem to run in parallel, *singleThread* makes no different here

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.system.*

val singleThread = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1).asCoroutineDispatcher()

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        val one = async { // async block #1
            delay(200)
            println("async block #1")
            launch (singleThread) {
                delay(500)
                println("single thread block #1")
            }
            2
        }
        val two = async { // async block #2
            delay(100)
            println("async block #2")
            launch (singleThread) {
                delay(1500)
                println("single thread block #2")
            }
            1
        }
        println("The answer is ${one.await() + two.await()}")
    }
    println("Completed in $time ms")
}
```

Comment: I don't get why you're using async+launch. Anyway, `await()` in series should do what you want.

Comment: The `delay()` function suspends the execution of a coroutine and thus the dispatcher is free to run another coroutine while waiting for the delay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mind the `delay()` is `suspend` function in the code. It is implemented via coroutine suspension. It means that the execution of the code is suspended at the moment when you call the `delay` and only resumed after the timeout. The thread (for example one that you use via `async(singleThread) {..}` is not busy waiting to the time to elapse.

The overall scenario looks like that

- ...
- the "async block #2" printed
- task 2 is running on the `singleThread`
- task 2 is suspended with `delay(1500)`, the `singleThread` is free
- task 1 is started on the `singleThread`
- task 1 is suspended with `delay(500)`, the `singleThread` is free
- at that point we have the delay queue:

  - resume the `delay(500)` for task 1
  - resume the `delay(1500)` for task 2
- after some time
- `resume(500)` schedules the second part of task 1 to run in the `singleThread`
- after some time
- `resume(1500)` schedules the second part of task 2 to run in the `singleThread`

Comment: thanks you for very well explanation, so there's nothing wrong with singleThread but using delay() is wrong for long-running task assumption

Comment: I'm quite curious what will happen if delay() is replaced by a "real suspend function" - i.e., writing to disk, call network API function? It will run sequentially?

Comment: Great question [Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377819/hoang-nguyen-huu)! The answer is: it depends. If the "real suspend function" moves its work to another thread, we would have the same output. But in case it doesn't do it, it will really "block" the single thread. Meaning, the single thread will not getting "freed" (as explained in this answer), but instead finish his work first. But again, if the function suspend and move the work to another thread, we would have the same output. I hope this make sense ...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the @EugenePetrenko answer the is a new method [`CoroutineDispatcher.limitedParallelism(numberOfParallelism)`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-dispatcher/limited-parallelism.html?query=open%20fun%20limitedParallelism(parallelism:%20Int):%20CoroutineDispatcher), which you can use to guarantees the parallelism restriction - at most 1 coroutine can be executed concurrently in this dispatcher. It will look like:

```
val singleThread = Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(1)

someCoroutineScope.launch (singleThread) {
    ...
}
```

Function `limitedParallelism` is available starting from the [1.6.0](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/12/introducing-kotlinx-coroutines-1-6-0/#dispatcher-views-api) version of the `kotlinx.coroutines` library.